# what does it mean?casting char* to unsigned int

Tags: c

I read some codes below:

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;    
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;

inline uint16_t NS(uint16_t i16)
{
    return((i16 << 8) | (i16 >> 8));
}

inline uint32_t NL(uint32_t i32)
{
    return((uint32_t(NS(i32)) << 16) | NS(i32>>16));
}

char* data = (char*) malloc(10);

strcpy(data, "123456789");
const char *m_data = (const char *)data;
uint32_t i32 = *((uint32_t*)m_data);
i32 = NL(i32);
m_data += 4u;
```

I don't understand `uint32_t i32 = *((uint32_t*)m_data);`,what does it mean?

And don't understand     `i32 = NL(i32);   m_data += 4u;` and the function NS and NL.

can someone tell me?

Comment: @Kevin Apart from breaking aliasing there is no problem.

Comment: @2501 My bad, I read it as storing a pointer in a uint32 at some point, not a uint32*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is buggy (it leaks memory):

```
char* data = (char*) malloc(10);
data="123456789\0";
```

should be:

```
char* data = (char*) malloc(10);
strcpy(data, "123456789");
```

It also means that you can't tell anything about the alignment of the pointer in `data`, whereas the assignment from `malloc()` guarantees the data is sufficiently well aligned for any basic type.
However, that's partly tangential to the issue of the next two lines:

```
const char *m_data = (const char *)data;
uint32_t i32 = *((uint32_t*)m_data);
```

The cast in the first of those lines is unnecessary, but does no harm.  The next line treats the pointer stored in `m_data` as a `uint32_t` pointer, dereferences it, and assigns the result to `i32`.  If the value in `m_data` came from `data` which came from `malloc()`, the data would be sufficiently well aligned for this not to be a problem.  With the string assignment, there is no guarantee that the pointer in `m_data` is well enough aligned to be used as a `uint32_t` pointer.  So all hell might break loose, or you might be fine.  The behaviour is undefined because of the memory leak.

The `NS()` function byte-swaps a 16-bit integer.  The `NL()` function swaps 16-bit values within a 32-bit integer.  That means you start with the value shown in the 'Start' diagram and end up with the value shown in the 'Finish' diagram.

```
+------+------+------+------+
|  MSB | NMSB | NLSB |  LSB |   Start
+------+------+------+------+

+------+------+------+------+
|  LSB | NLSB | NMSB |  MSB |   Finish
+------+------+------+------+
```

The `m_data += 4u;` adds 4 to the pointer `m_data`, so instead of pointing at the `1` of the string, it points at the `5`.

Comment: The [casting of the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)  can be removed.

Comment: uint32_t i32 = *((uint32_t*)m_data);  what is the result?

Comment: It depends on the platform — you get different results on Intel compared with say SPARC or Power (little-endian vs big-endian).  On big-endian, you get 0x31323334; on little-endian, you get 0x34333231.  What did you get when you ran it?  Or did it crash?

Comment: get 0x34333231.But I don't understand why to cast.Actually,the datas were from network.

Comment: You cast because if you write `uint32_t i32 = *m_data;` you only get the value from the single byte that `m_data` points at (because it is a `const char *`), so the value without the cast would be 0x31.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint32_t i32 = *((uint32_t*)m_data);
```

This literally means to take interpret the pointer `m_data` as a pointer to `uint32_t` and dereference it. The intent is to interpret the characters specified by `data` as a `uint32_t`.

The functions NS and NL appear to be taking the bitwise OR of the left and right halves of their parameters and returning it.

```
m_data += 4u;
```

This should be equivalent to the same statement without the unsigned suffix. It just increments the pointer `m_data` to point at the character at the address four characters above where it was pointing before.

Answer (score 0):

When `NS` is given a 16-bit value `i16` thus (each character being one bit):

```
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
```

then the expression `i16 << 8` (bit-shift left by 8 bits, feeding in zero-bits on the right) will give you `bbbbbbbb00000000` and `i16 >> 8` will give `00000000aaaaaaaa`. ORing those together gives:

```
   bbbbbbbb00000000
OR 00000000aaaaaaaa
   ----------------
   bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
```

In other words, it's swapping the two bytes.

Ditto for the `N32` function swapping 16-bit halves within a 32-bit value but, because it also calls `N16` on each of those halves, it performs the following conversion:

```
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd
               ||
               VV
ddddddddccccccccbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
```

This is commonly used when converting to or from network-byte order when the ordering is different on your particular architecture.

---

The statement series:

```
const char *m_data = somethingOrOther;
uint32_t i32 = *((uint32_t*)m_data);
```

works as follows. First it converts the character pointer to a 32-bit-value pointer. Then, it dereferences that pointer to extract the 32-bit value.

What this means is that the first four characters of the string (assuming `char` data type is eight bits) of `"1234"` will be treated as a 32-bit integer value, and passed to `N32` to undergo the above-mentioned byte-swapping stuff.

And, finally, the `m_data += 4u` simply adds the unsigned value `4` to the character pointer so that it advances to the *next* 32-bit value (at `"5678"`).